# splitting dictionay values in a for loop in nested json conversion into a csv file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this nested json file converted into csv file. The json file is shown below:

```
jsonFile = {
         '7': {
               '11': {'ref1': 1}
              }, 

         '5': {
               '15':  {'ref1':0, 'ref3':1},
               '17':  {'ref2':1}, 
               '19':  {'ref1':1,'ref4':0}
              }, 

        '3': {
               '21':  {'ref3':1, 'ref2':1}, 
               '14':  {'ref5':0}
             },
      .... so on
        }
```

The desired csv file structure is:

```
    key,  subKey,  references, values
     7,    11,       ref1,       1
     5,    15,       ref1,       0 
     5,    15        ref3,       1
     5,    17,       ref2,       1
     5,    19,       ref1,       1
     5,    19,       ref4,       0
     3,    21,       ref3,       1
     3,    21,       ref2,       1
     3,    14,       ref5,       0
     ...... and so on
```

I used the following code:

```
 all_data = []
   for k, v in jsonFile.items():
      for t, val in v.items():
          for p, vall in val.items():
            all_data.append({
              'key': k,
              'subKey': t,
              'references': val,
              #'values': vall
            })

 df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
 df.to_csv('outPutFile3.csv', encoding='utf-8')
 print(df)
```

The output of the code is given below. I am not able to further split the dictionaries with ref values in the third loop as shown below:

```
    key,  subKey,     references
     7,    11,       {'ref1':1}
     5,    15,       {'ref1':0, 'ref3':1}
     5,    17,       {'ref2':1}
     5,    19,       {'ref1':1,'ref4':0}
     3,    21,       {'ref3':1, 'ref2':1},
     3,    14,       {'ref5':0}
     ..........
```

How can i further split the dictionaries into further columns in the required format?

Thank you..

Comment: `'references': val,` is likely a typo. Did you mean `'references': vall,` with the extra `l`?

Comment: @roganjosh No i meant the same as if i remove # from # 'values': vall, it will print ones and zeros as the values of the dictionary keys. The code is giving me the output i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution that descends into the `dict`. You should of course make sure that the structure is homogeneous enough to support this apprach (will fail if you are missing nested dictionaries):

```
import pandas as pd

jsonFile = {
         '7': {
               '11': {'ref1': 1}
              }, 

         '5': {
               '15':  {'ref1':0, 'ref3':1},
               '17':  {'ref2':1}, 
               '19':  {'ref1':1,'ref4':0}
              }, 

        '3': {
               '21':  {'ref3':1, 'ref2':1}, 
               '14':  {'ref5':0}
             }
}

def flatten_dict(d, parent_keys=None):
    parent_keys = parent_keys or []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for values in flatten_dict(v, parent_keys=parent_keys + [k]):
                yield values
        else:
            yield parent_keys + [k, v]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(flatten_dict(jsonFile)), columns=("key", "subkey", "references", "values"))
df
```

Output:

```
    key subkey  references  values
0   7   11      ref1        1
1   5   15      ref1        0
2   5   15      ref3        1
3   5   17      ref2        1
4   5   19      ref1        1
5   5   19      ref4        0
6   3   21      ref3        1
7   3   21      ref2        1
8   3   14      ref5        0
```

Then you can finish this up with `df.to_csv()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sim. Perhaps a more elegant and robust solution than what i coded.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are quite close. You can try following where I noted the change in comments. You need `p` and `vall` instead.

```
all_data = []
for k, v in jsonFile.items():
    for t, val in v.items():
        for p, vall in val.items():
            all_data.append({
              'key': k,
              'subKey': t,
              'references': p, #  <- change here
              'values':vall   #  <- change here
            })
```

Comment: @ student Thanks a lot. Now i feel stupid as while experimenting, i did once change the references to p and then may be i did not put much effort to notice the results.